# Calling a WebAPI controller action that has 2 parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI controller action that has 2 parameters.
How do i call this action?

With a single parameter, my code works good.
How do i call a WebAPI that has 2 parameters?
I tried couple of ways and it does not work.
I have a WebAPI controller action that has 2 parameters.
How do i call this action?

With a single parameter, my code works good.
How do i call a WebAPI that has 2 parameters?
I tried couple of ways and it does not work.

Thanks in Advance

```
//With a single parameter it works good:
[Route("api/Controller/GetAllVendors")]
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Vendor> GetAllVendors(LoginParameters loginParam)
{
}

function LoadVendorLkup() {
    alert("InVendorCall");
    var loginPar = {
    UserName: 'user1',
    CompanyID: 'company1',
    ProgramID: ''
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/Controller/GetAllVendors',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(loginPar), 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//With 2 parameters , it does not work:

[Route("api/Controller/GetVendorsForSelectedHouseholdID")]
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Vendor> GetVendorsForSelectedHouseholdID(LoginParameters loginParam, string hHoldID)
{
}

function LoadVendorLkupForSelectedHousehold() {
    var hHoldtext = $('#txtHHold').val();
    var loginPar = {
    UserName: 'user1',
    CompanyID: 'company1',
    ProgramID: ''
}
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/controller/GetVendorsForSelectedHouseholdID',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(loginPar), 'hHoldID': hHoldtext,
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//I also tried the following:
[Route("api/controller/GetVendorsForSelectedHouseholdID/{hHoldID:String}")]
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Vendor> GetVendorsForSelectedHouseholdID([FromBody()]LoginParameters loginParam,[FromUri()]string hHoldID)
{
}

function LoadVendorLkupForSelectedHousehold() {
    alert("InVendorCall2");
    var hHoldtext = $('#txtHHold').val();
    alert("Household:" + hHoldtext);
    var loginPar = {
    UserName: 'user1',
    CompanyID: 'company1',
    ProgramID: ''
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/controller/GetVendorsForSelectedHouseholdID?hHoldID='+ hHoldtext,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(loginPar),
```

Comment: Generically speaking, what you send to a controller is a "view model". It is OK if it does not match a particular class in the backend exactly because you can parse it out however you need to. So, why not add `hHoldID` to the `LoginParameters` or make a new class that represents the view model?

Comment: Adding hHoldID to LoginParameters is the last option for me. I would still like to know how to call when there are 2 parameters. The ones that i tried are not working. Any thing wrong with the way i am calling?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use multiple parameters if one of them is a complex type. I think you can only use primitives and strings but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple [FromBody] attributes on POST parameters would not work as mentioned [in the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

```
// Caution: Will not work!    
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

> The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a
>   non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

[This blog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods) specifies that there are 3 simple methods to achieve this:

1. Use Both POST and GET (one parameter from post other parameter from the query string)
2. Create 1 model which encapsulate all values inside single model
3. Use JSON.Stringify to pass single JSON to API and then use JObject as parameter in web api.  Then parse JSON in the web api.

There is one more option - you can also create custom binder using IModelBinder as mentioned in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api